# How to use fetchmany() to fetch the next set of results?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to fetch a hundred of results from MySql using fetchmany(100) in Python. But I am wondering if there's a way to fetch the next set of results in case what I want is not available in the fetched results. So it will be something like, fetch the next 100 results.

Is this possible? And if yes then how can it be done?!

Comment: I wonder why I got a negative vote without any comment!

Comment: it is not clear what problem you were trying to solve, or an example of where this could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using fetchmany(), you can use fetchall(), but include in your select query the following:

```
SELECT * from data limit 00,30;
```

The `00` indicates the position
The `30` indicates the number of the rows you want to output as the result.

Hence, you can make introduce the position using a variable that increases every time you want to fetch more results.

E.g

```
position= 00
while True:
    nothing = input("Do you want more input?")

    data = c.execute("SELECT * from data limit {}, 50".format(amount))
    data = c.fetchall()
    position += 50
```

Comment: Whilst this solution may work its bad practice. SQL databases by default are non deterministic (i.e. you cannot reply on the order of the rows returned).

Comment: To achieve what you intend you will need to add an order by statement that forces the return data to be deterministic