# python loop over sqlite select with .fetchmany() until no entries left

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to retrieve results from my sqlite3 database 160 rows at a time, and repeat that until there are no rows left for my query, this is what I have:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Roaming\\GridcoinResearch\\reports\\Rain.db" % user_account)
c = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = str
address = c.execute('select Address from NNDATA where NeuralMagnitude != 0 and NeuralMagnitude is not null and CPID in (select cpids from GRIDCOINTEAM)').fetchmany(160)
conn.text_factory = float
nn_mag = c.execute('select NeuralMagnitude from NNDATA where NeuralMagnitude != 0 and NeuralMagnitude is not null and CPID in (select cpids from GRIDCOINTEAM)').fetchmany(160)
conn.close()

while True:
    if nn_mag == ():
        sys.exit("Complete")
```

The reason for `sys.exit` is I have a bunch of other code to go between `conn.close()` and `while True:`, so when the last loop is done I can exit the program.  Right now its doing the first pass then the cmd.exe is hanging.

EDIT: Just relaised I dont tell the loop to select the NEXT 160, oh dear!

Comment: `nn_mag` isn't being updated at all in the `while` loop, so if it's not empty the first time around, it's never going to be, and the loop will just hang. I'm not really sure what the intent of that particular block is.

Comment: the point to to select 160 rows, do some other work on them, go back get the next 160 rows, do some work on them, until there are no rows left.  Im a novice, so I know the code is wrong, I just cant figure out how.

Comment: Have a look at [this so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345177/how-to-use-fetchmany-to-fetch-the-next-set-of-results#37359923) question. You should change your sql query

Comment: @576i That approach is more appropriate for asynchronous situations like web client queries and such. If he's just processing through all the records a chunk at a time, I think selecting all in the query and fetching them in chunks is the less complex and error-prone way to go.

Answer (score 6):

The `fetchmany` attribute returns an empty list if there is no item lefts so you can just check the validation of its result. Also note that you should remove the `limit` from your query and the `fetchall`. Because the whole essence of using `fetchmany` is to fetch limited results from your cursor object.

```
chunk_size = 160
while True:
    result = nn_mag.fetchmany(chunk_size)
    if not result:
        sys.exit("Complete")
    else:
         # do something with result
```

Comment: Im getting an error:
    result = nn_mag.fetchmany(160)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetchmany'

Comment: @Scalextrix It seems that `nn_mag` is a list object not a query result. Look where you converted that to list!

Comment: I changed my code to  magnitude_db = c.execute('select NeuralMagnitude from NNDATA where NeuralMagnitude != 0 and NeuralMagnitude is not null and CPID in (select cpids from GRIDCOINTEAM)').fetchmany(160)

I now get the error:     result = magnitude_db.fetchmany(160)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetchmany'

Comment: OK if i take .fetchmany(160) off of the magnitude_db = c.execute(), then I dont get the error, but I only get 160 results, there is no loop

Comment: @Scalextrix Now, I see. You have a `fetchall()` at the end of your query. please remove that and also the limit. then just use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK the full answer is:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Roaming\\GridcoinResearch\\reports\\Rain.db" % user_account)
    c = conn.cursor()
    position = 00
    while True:
        conn.text_factory = str
        address_db = c.execute('select Address from NNDATA where NeuralMagnitude != 0 and NeuralMagnitude is not null and CPID in (select cpids from GRIDCOINTEAM) limit {}, 160'.format(position)).fetchall()
        conn.text_factory = float
        rac_db = c.execute('select rac from GRIDCOINTEAM where rac != 0 and rac is not null limit {}, 160'.format(position)).fetchall()
        if not address_db:
            conn.close()
            sys.exit("Complete")
        else:
            position += 160
```